# Binance is there a way to sell the small balances in python?

Tags: python, binance, binance-smart-chain

I am trying to use the binance api and would like to use dust to bnb conversion?
We can do this on the binance website and I would like to automate this

I searched the binance api but couldn't find anything.

Thanks for yours answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Binance has this in API document:

[image]

Btw, this question is not appropriate for stackoverflow, since you're trying to find a resource or tool, not asking a specific programming question. It's better to be posted on binance support forum.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, and sorry for the "misstake", i didn't know it :)

Comment: i close the question